# Indian tourist visa

Tags: visas, india

What happens if I can't use my Indian tourist visa within the stipulated time? Will I get another visa if I apply for soon?

Answer (score 3):

Question seems about to be closed for lack of clarity, so I am going to guess:

a) You would like to know the consequences of applying for a visa, being successful with your application but not then attempting to visit India during the period of validity of the visa

and

b) would you be granted another visa shortly after your previous one has expired if you never made use of your previous one.

And taking these in turn:

a) None
b) The short interval leaves little opportunity for your circumstances to change significantly, you clearly provided the information required previously, so "know the ropes", hence the result will very likely be the same as it was last time - ie a visa. You might want to explain *why* you never made use of the previous visa as there is a *little* taint to your credibility by not managing what you intended.